# Preventing static injection when using builder pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

### Introduction

I'm using Dagger 2 for a project that's modeled using the principles of [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

I'd like to use the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to create complex entities and the way I'd normally get an instance of the builder was by using a static factory method: `ComplexEntity.builder()`.

Aggregate roots will get strongly typed IDs, i.e. `ComplexEntityID`, that require a value generator for new instances. Right now I have a method for that in my module: `@Provides ComplexEntityID provideComplexEntityID(IdValueGenerator generator) { return new ComplexEntityID(generator.nextId(); }`.

`ComplexEntityBuilder` needs an instance (or provider) of `ComplexEntityID` in order to create a `ComplexEntity`. But static injection is recommended against by the people from Guice and Dagger (among others) for good reasons.

### Question

How to create instances of `ComplexEntity` using a builder, without using static injection? In other words, how to get an instance of the builder?

Sticking to `ComplexEntity.builder()` would be nice because it's a common convention, but I'd think that the only way to make an instance available in a static method without using the `new ()` keyword is by using static injection.

Another approach I could think of is to also create `ComplexEntityFactory` and put the `builder()` method there. But it seems a bit strange to use a factory and a builder together:

1. Inject a factory in the class where you need it
2. `complexEntityFactory.builder().value1(...)
                                  .value2(...)
                                  .build();`

What would be the recommended approach in this case?

**Edit**: If it turns out to a dedicated factory after all, tt would be nice if this factory could still be generated using [AutoFactory](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory) or something similar

Comment: You could pass the `ComplexEntityID` into the static factory method: `ComplexEntity.builder(complexEntityID)`. It's not unusual for a builder's constructor to take required parameters.

Comment: I guess that's a reasonable solution. It does imply that wherever I would need to build a `ComplexEntity` I would have a dependency on `Provider<ComplexEntityID>` though.

Comment: @jaco0646 As a consumer of an API, would you find `ComplexEntity.builder(ComplexEntityID id)` that needs an instance of `Provider<ComplexEntityID>` more intuitive/usable than acquiring an instance of `ComplexEntityFactory` and get the builder from there (considering either approach would used be consistently throughout the application)?

Comment: It depends on whether the consumer is otherwise aware of that ID. I would not introduce the ID to the API only for this purpose; but if the consumer uses the ID elsewhere, then little conceptual overhead is added by using it again.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @jaco0646 . The consumer would be aware of that ID, but only for reference and never for instantiation (created on the fly for new entities, or deserialized for existing). I experimented for a while and realized that a name change would make a difference; I ended up with a `BuilderFactory`, which contains all the relevant builders for a particular bounded context. It's primarily for commands, so this provides a nice central place in the API from where to build commands for that context. E.g. `workspaceCommandBuilderFactory.archiveWorkspace()...build();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a more elegant solution than the one proposed by jaco0646 in the comment:

Builders are a special kind of service: You use them to realize a specific goal, but they don't have a life cycle or meaning within the domain.

**So just inject builders as you would any other service.**

This has several advantages:

- Builders can use other services and factories by depending on them. In your case this is the dependency on the factory of `ComplexEntityID`.
- Having a dependency on a builder is explicit (which is a good thing). At the moment, your dependency is hidden in a call to a static method.
- You can replace the builder in tests.

**Overall, this approach improves cohesion and reduces coupling.**

One potential pitfall to be aware of is that builders usually have internal state (unlike typical services). So make sure to configure your dependency injection container such that a new builder instance is created for every resolve request.

Comment: Thanks @theDmi, I think that's the most elegant solution indeed. What I ended up doing is to inject a builder that contains all the builders of a particular type for an aggregate. So for the `Workspace` aggregate, all commands can be built by injecting `WorkspaceCommandBuilder`. It has one method for each command that returns the builder of that command, used like this: `workspaceCommandBuilder.archiveWorkspace()...build()`, or `workspaceCommandBuilder.addWorkspace()....build()`. Looking at class `WorkspaceCommandBuilder` it may not be a real builder, but in actual api usage it's just the same